# How to join two columns if one of them or both can be NULL

Tags: python, pandas

I have Excel table as example:

[image: example table]

And need to join columns x and y together and get new column z, but x or y or both can be None.
I've tried method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
df['z'] = (df[['x', 'y']]
                .apply(lambda x: ','.join([i for i in x if i]), axis=1))
print(df)
```

But it gives me an error: *TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found*

What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you storing sequences in your data frame? What will you do with that data? I recommend either tidying/normalizing your data or switching to a standard library-based data structure like a list of dictionaries (of lists)

Comment: please provide your input as `DataFrame` constructor, an image is ambiguous and not reproducible

Comment: Does `df['z'] = df[['x', 'y']].fillna('').apply(lambda x: ','.join([i for i in x if i]), axis=1)` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost correct, as people said before - you should fill out these `NaN`s, as you cannot concatenate them with strings, to get it back to where we started you can use the `replace` method of pandas:

```py
df['z'] = df[['x', 'y']].fillna('').apply(lambda x: ','.join([_ for _ in x if _]), axis=1).replace('', np.nan)
```

Of course it will not be 100% perfect as if you want to keep empty cells with an empty string - it will replace it with a `NaN` - but Excel-wise you will not detect any differences.

In Python though, you would see some small details, `df['z']`'s third row's type is a `float` and not a string, and `df` will now look like:

```
  order         x      y               z
0    a1        x1     y1           x1,y1
1    a2       NaN     y2              y2
2    a3       NaN    NaN             NaN
3    a4  x5,x6,x7  y5,y6  x5,x6,x7,y5,y6
4    a5     x3,x4    NaN           x3,x4
```

And not:

```
  order         x      y               z
0    a1        x1     y1           x1,y1
1    a2       NaN     y2              y2
2    a3       NaN    NaN                
3    a4  x5,x6,x7  y5,y6  x5,x6,x7,y5,y6
4    a5     x3,x4    NaN           x3,x4
```

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs because when you read the excel with pandas, for empty values pandas reads it as `np.nan` which is a float.

Now when you join a `str` and `float` you will get that `TypeError`.

If you want to just concatenate the two columns just use:

```
df['z'] = (df['x'].fillna('') + ',' + df['y'].fillna('')).str.strip(',')
```

OR

```
df['x'].fillna('').str.cat(df['y'].fillna(''), sep=',').str.strip(',')
```